# Java special character encoding

Tags: java, json, unicode, encoding

I'm having trouble encoding java special characters returned from JSON data. I'm reading in a JSON file "raw.json", and certain names are giving me trouble. 
For Example, I'm reading in the name 'Martin Perénya' from the JSON file and I'm to push it to a JsonArray of JsonObjects, with the special characters in the form of UNICODE like 'Martin Per\u00e9nya', but my code is interpreting it as 'Martin PerÃ©nya'. Can anyone help me with this please or even point me in the right direction? I'm new to this and not sure how to proceed, thanks.

```
package main.service;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;

public class Service {


    public String getAll() throws FileNotFoundException {

        JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();

        FileReader reader;
        reader = new FileReader("raw.json");
        JsonObject data = (JsonObject) jsonParser.parse(reader);


        JsonArray issues = data.get("issues").getAsJsonArray();     
        JsonArray processedIssues = new JsonArray();


        for(JsonElement i: issues) {
            JsonObject object = new JsonObject();
            JsonObject issue =(JsonObject) i;
            JsonObject fields = issue.get("fields").getAsJsonObject();

            //displayName
            JsonObject assignee = fields.get("assignee").getAsJsonObject();
            String name = assignee.get("displayName").getAsString();
            if(assignee.size() !=0) {

                if(name.length()==0) {
                    name = "None";
                }
                else {
                    name = assignee.get("displayName").getAsString();
                }
            }

            object.addProperty("name", name);
            processedIssues.add(object);
        }   


        JsonObject returnData = new JsonObject();
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        String dateString = format.format( new Date());
        returnData.addProperty("created", dateString);
        returnData.add("featureList", processedIssues);

        System.out.println("returnedData - " +returnData);




        return returnData.toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: implement this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/37021602/8035260

Comment: @JosePraveen: please don't. Read any of the countless higher-votes answers to that question to understand what is going on instead of mindlessly encoding and decoding a string with basically random encodings, that's not an appropriate solution for this problem.

Comment: `FileReader` will use the platform default encoding, but JSON is *usually* written with the UTF-8 encoding. Use a `FileInputStream` and an `InputStreamReader` and construct the second one while passing in the `"UTF-8"` string to tell it about the encoding.

Comment: The good thing about the link to that "solution" was that there were a lot of answers that needed downvoting...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read write this in utf-8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13350676/how-to-read-write-this-in-utf-8)

Comment: [1] I hesitate to mark your question as a duplicate of [Java - é becomes Ã© - How to fix it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16208517/2985643), but take a look since it might be helpful. [2] Update your question to show some sample data in **raw.json** so that others can try to replicate/resolve your issue.